# apt-get for a particular version?

Tags: aptitude

I would like the linux (Ubuntu) version of jdk 6 update 17 (which I think is one version behind the current one), can apt-get request such a specific package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want:

```
apt-get install package=version
```

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to add something like this to your /etc/apt/preferences file, so that it won't just get upgraded again next time you run `apt-get upgrade`:

```
Package: sun-java6-jdk
Pin: version 6-17-*
Pin-Priority: 1001
```