# How do I tell aptitude or apt to offer a particular version of lpr?

Tags: debian, aptitude, debian-squeeze, lpr

I seem to have a weird version of lpr installed (one that doesn't cope with -o, see also [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/230379/adobe-reader-seems-to-use-wrong-lpr-command-when-printing-to-cups)). On all my other machines that run the same debian squeeze, the proper version of lpr is installed.

How can I get aptitude to install the "good" lpr?

Note: The contents of /etc/apt/sources.list are not the problem, I guess. The file is the same on all machines.

Edit: [A related question is here.](https://superuser.com/questions/95938/apt-get-for-a-particular-version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lpr can be installed via

- the lpr package (obvoius)
- the lprng package (a little less obvious)
- the cups-bsd package (not very obvious)

The three versions are not exactly the same and work a bit differently. They accept, for example, different options while being called.

See also [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/77970/finding-manuals-for-lpr/78062#78062).

Answer (score 1):

Man pages mention:

> A specific version of a package can be selected for installation by following the package name with an equals (=) and the version of the package to select

So it'll be something like

```
$ apt-get install lpr=<version>
```